# lemma from Milne

Tags: abstract-algebra, self-learning

I am reading Milne book on algebraic geometry. I understood the proof presented below. I don't understand why use A[x] ? Why not proceed with the proof by using A[X]/(1 - hX)? x isn't defined anywhere.

[image]

Comment: First paragraph $A[x]=A[X]/(1-hX)$...

Comment: I don’t understand why not just work with A[X]/(1 - hX) why does it work with A[x]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Milne's phrasing in the second sentence of the proof is a little bit informal with notation, but for clarity, you could insert the following sentence immediately before that:

> Let $x$ be the class of $X$ in the quotient ring $A[X]/(1 - hX)$.

So, in particular, $A[x]$ isn't a polynomial ring over $A$ in one indeterminate $x$ (i.e., the ring over $A$ generated by an element $x$ with *no* relations other than those implied by the commutative ring axioms), but rather it's the ring over $A$ generated by an element $x$ that's subject to the relation $hx = 1$.

Comment: Yes, this was what I was being confused about. Thank you for clarifying.